# Nested .so libraries to hide class from user

Tags: c++, inheritance, cmake, shared-libraries

I’m creating a project in which I want someone else to be able to modify a main.cpp file, defining objects of a class B, which inherits from class A. But I want the user not to be able to instantiate objects of class A.

Can I use this structure or is there a better way?

```
├── Alpha
│   ├── alpha.cpp
│   └── alpha.hpp
├── Beta
│   ├── beta.cpp
│   └── beta.hpp
├── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

Class beta depends on alpha, main depends on beta.

If I build beta using the .so of alpha. Will user in main still be able to define alpha? Is this the correct way to ship a main.cpp file with access to class B and not to class A? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look into the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: Usually on a pure C++ level you simply add at least one pure virtual member function to `A` which means no instance of the object can be created. The library must contain the constructor/destructor logic for `A` though which means if the user provides an alternative definition of `A` to the compiler not containing a pure virtual function, they'll probably be able to get around this restriction... Btw: since we're discussing classes and inheritance: why are all the source files in your project C files instead of C++ files?

Comment: Hi fabian, if i give the .so files for class A and class B, will he be able to define A even if he lacks the header of A? I wrote project structure and code just to clarify and is not the working project, of course those are .cpp files I'll edit the question, thanks.

Comment: C language and C compiler may prevent a user from **unintentional** instantiation of a class which is defined in a library's header. But nothing (neither C language, nor a compiler, nor .so file, etc.) can prevent a user to intentionally "hack" your system by writing a header which defines his/her variant of the class and instantiate it. So, which kind of "hiding" you are talking about?

Comment: I’m talking about the intentional hack. What I need to do is provide a main.cpp to a user which should be able to instantiate object of type B. But I need to preclude him the possibility of instantiating objects of class A. Is this shared object nesting useful as I wouldn’t provide him the .h file of class A?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two separate requests here:

- If you want to allow construction of objects of type B but not of type A from which B inherits, make the ctor of A protected.
- If you want the library which contains Bbl to link against A but you do not want main to link against A, declare A private when linking against it in B (target_link_library(B PRIVATE A)